# How to make space between array values in printing?

Tags: c++

I'm interested, how could i get same result in C++. For this C code:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%4d",array[i]);
```

This will create 4 space gap between my values from array.

Is there something similar in C++?

Comment: cout<<array[i]<<"    "; Have four spaces

Comment: Why not just use the same code?

Comment: @pavanchandaka Is this mean i have to type `cout<<" ";` 4 times?

Comment: No. cout<<"space1 space2 space3 space4";

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw

Comment: It does not create a "4 space gap". It sets the minimum amount of characters to be printed 4. If the number is smaller, spaces will be added. The c++ equivalent is `std::setw`.

Comment: @paq Thanks a lot, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same code works in C++:

```
const int n = 10;
int array[n] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%4d",array[i]);
```

But if you're looking for more a C++-esque way of doing things, you can use [`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) and [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw):

```
#include <iostream> // cout
#include <iomanip> // setw
int main()
{
    int array[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };       
    for (auto n : array)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << n;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what two of guys said in comments, but thanks again for full answer. :D